# How to get larger font size to render correctly in slick2d

Tags: java, fonts, slick2d

In Slick2d when I try to render text with a font size of lets say 92 it renders the font incorrectly. When I use the Graphics.drawString method with a font that size it will show up as random bars on the screen.

Here is some of my code on how I load it an draw it onto the screen

Loading Font

```
try {
    awtFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("res" + File.separator + "font.ttf"));
} catch (FontFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Getting Specific Font Size

```
public static org.newdawn.slick.Font getFont(float size){
    return new TrueTypeFont(awtFont.deriveFont(size), false);
}
```

Drawing the text

```
g.setFont(title);
float x = ((float)gc.getWidth() - title.getWidth("Neon")) / 2f;
float y = ((float)gc.getHeight() - title.getLineHeight()) / 2f;

g.setColor(Color.white);
g.drawString("NEON", x, y);


//this is only in the init method.
title = Neon.getFont(92f * Neon.getK());
```